# How to enable Office Communicator presentation mode programmatically

Tags: vbscript, lync, office-communicator

I know that at least PowerPoint presentation mode will enable the OC / Lync presentation mode where the actual messages are not visible in the screen.

http://www.ultimate-communications.com/2012/05/privacy-tips-use-presentation-mode-when-you-dont-want-someone-to-see-the-content-of-an-im-in-the-toast-lync/

Is there any way to enable or disable the setting from a web page script (e.g. VBS)?

Answer (score 0):

Some more details about the functionality:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/adjust-settings-before-giving-a-presentation

**SHQueryUserNotificationState** should be the method that can be used to **Query** the value but how to change it..?